# Querying a single-row DataFrame with AND'ed conditionals

Tags: python, pandas

Using pandas 0.13, I have a single-row DataFrame:

```
In [23]: is_same
Out[23]:
       bid bidsize    ask asksize
168  False   False  False   False

[1 rows x 4 columns]
```

I can query this with Python syntax:

```
In [24]: is_same.bid & is_same.ask
Out[24]:
168    False
dtype: bool
```

The trouble comes when I use the pandas `query()` method. A simple condition is fine:

```
In [25]: is_same.query('bid')
Out[25]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [bid, bidsize, ask, asksize]
Index: []

[0 rows x 4 columns]
```

But if want to AND the booleans like I do above, I get an error:

```
In [26]: is_same.query('bid & ask')
...

KeyError: 'the label [False] is not in the [index]'
```

Is this a bug? Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

might be a bug; boolean handling like this I don't think has been completely tested
(the evaluating to booleans of course is, e.g. 'values>0'); you already have the result

You can do this

```
In [5]: df.query('bid==False and ask==False')
Out[5]: 
       bid bidsize    ask asksize
168  False   False  False   False

[1 rows x 4 columns]

In [6]: df.query('bid==False and ask==True')
Out[6]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [bid, bidsize, ask, asksize]
Index: []

[0 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6148 as I wrote; have to think about how/why this should actually work

Comment: FYI I used 'and' here but '&' is ok too (query/eval have a somewhat relaxed parsing)

Comment: Follow up: this is now fixed in pandas github master: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/6163